# Add an occasion flag to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

For each individual, I would like to add an occasion flag for my data frame when the amount is bigger than zero. I need this flag for further calculations. Here what I would like to achieve.

```
dfin <- 

ID AMT 
1  50
1  NA
1  10
1  NA
2  15
2  NA
2  NA
3  10
3  15

dfout <- 

ID  AMT FLAG
1   50   1
1   NA   1
1   10   2
1   NA   2
2   15   1
2   NA   1
2   NA   1
3   10   1
3   15   2
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have changed the output that I want. I am here answering the question based on the answer provided by @G5W to make it by `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
dfout <- dfin %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(FLAG = cumsum(!is.na(AMT)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can test which values are not NA and compute the cumulative sum.

```
dfout = dfin
dfout$FLAG = cumsum(!is.na(dfin$AMT))
dfout
  ID AMT FLAG
1  1  50    1
2  1  NA    1
3  1  10    2
4  1  NA    2
5  2  15    3
6  2  NA    3
7  2  NA    3
8  3  10    4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! sorry i have slightly changed the output that I want. Can we do it per `ID`